# I have a problem with my jquery in the loadmask section, which is that the data refresh doesn't want to stop, is it true the problem from my js?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, css

Yesterday this website was normal, but recently I had a problem like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKX9k.png)

Data refresh doesn't stop so that the data cannot be accessed, but if the URL on the error is clicked then the correct data can be seen and accessed
this is my `jquery.loadmask.js =`

```
/**
 * Displays loading mask over selected element(s). Accepts both single and multiple selectors.
 *
 * @param label Text message that will be displayed on top of the mask besides a spinner (optional). 
 *              If not provided only mask will be displayed without a label or a spinner.   
 * @param delay Delay in milliseconds before element is masked (optional). If unmask() is called 
 *              before the delay times out, no mask is displayed. This can be used to prevent unnecessary 
 *              mask display for quick processes.       
 */
$.fn.mask = function(label, delay){
    $(this).each(function() {
        if(delay !== undefined && delay > 0) {
            var element = $(this);
            element.data("_mask_timeout", setTimeout(function() { $.maskElement(element, label)}, delay));
        } else {
            $.maskElement($(this), label);
        } 
    });
};

/**
 * Removes mask from the element(s). Accepts both single and multiple selectors.
 */
$.fn.unmask = function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
        $.unmaskElement($(this));
    });
};


/**
 * Checks if a single element is masked. Returns false if mask is delayed or not displayed. 
 */
$.fn.isMasked = function(){
    return this.hasClass("masked");
};

$.maskElement = function(element, label){

    //if this element has delayed mask scheduled then remove it and display the new one
    if (element.data("_mask_timeout") !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(element.data("_mask_timeout"));
        element.removeData("_mask_timeout");
    }

    if(element.isMasked()) {
        $.unmaskElement(element);
    }
    
    if(element.css("position") == "static") {
        element.addClass("masked-relative");
    }
    
    element.addClass("masked");
    
    var maskDiv = $('<div class="loadmask"></div>');
    
    //auto height fix for IE
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1){
        maskDiv.height(element.height() + parseInt(element.css("padding-top")) + parseInt(element.css("padding-bottom")));
        maskDiv.width(element.width() + parseInt(element.css("padding-left")) + parseInt(element.css("padding-right")));
    }
    
    //fix for z-index bug with selects in IE6
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 6") > -1){
        element.find("select").addClass("masked-hidden");
    }
    
    element.append(maskDiv);
    
    if(label !== undefined) {
        var maskMsgDiv = $('<div class="loadmask-msg" style="display:none;"></div>');
        maskMsgDiv.append('<div>' + label + '</div>');
        element.append(maskMsgDiv);
        
        //calculate center position
        maskMsgDiv.css("top", Math.round(element.height() / 2 - (maskMsgDiv.height() - parseInt(maskMsgDiv.css("padding-top")) - parseInt(maskMsgDiv.css("padding-bottom"))) / 2)+"px");
        maskMsgDiv.css("left", Math.round(element.width() / 2 - (maskMsgDiv.width() - parseInt(maskMsgDiv.css("padding-left")) - parseInt(maskMsgDiv.css("padding-right"))) / 2)+"px");
        
        maskMsgDiv.show();
    }
    
};

$.unmaskElement = function(element){
    //if this element has delayed mask scheduled then remove it
    if (element.data("_mask_timeout") !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(element.data("_mask_timeout"));
        element.removeData("_mask_timeout");
    }
    
    element.find(".loadmask-msg,.loadmask").remove();
    element.removeClass("masked");
    element.removeClass("masked-relative");
    element.find("select").removeClass("masked-hidden");
};
```

does anyone know how to fix it ? thank you

Comment: You can post your css classes please

Comment: you could create a snippet to reproduce the error